# add two zero with decimal if number is complete integer in Oracle SQL column

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

Column amount contains data like - 200.203, 200, 5.10, 45.20, 10 and 5000213.012

Now I want to select if the number does not include any decimal digit then we add .00 in the returning result.

Expected result - 200.203, 200.00 ,5.10, 45.20 , 10.00 and 5000213.012

Comment: The formatting of numbers is a function of the client. The app you're using to render your data will have a preference which allows you to specify a format.

Comment: What application are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_CHAR` to format the value so that it has at least 2 decimal places:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR( value, 'FM9999999990.009' ) AS formatted_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT     200.203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     200     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT       5.10  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT      45.20  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT      10     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5000213.012 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>       VALUE | FORMATTED_VALUE
> ----------: | :--------------
>     200.203 | 200.203        
>         200 | 200.00         
>         5.1 | 5.10           
>        45.2 | 45.20          
>          10 | 10.00          
> 5000213.012 | 5000213.012
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f637244df1643976bd8944c6432b13f0)*

---

Following some comments, the OP's question is effectively:

> How can I change this number to have a given format?

When you consider that a `NUMBER` data type has no format and `5`, `5.0` and `5.00000` are exactly the same value and the database does not store how many trailing zeroes a decimal value has then this question does not entirely make sense as there is no way to give a number a format.

Instead the question can be formulated as either:

> How can I get <insert name of client program> to display numbers so that they always have at least 2 decimal places?

We can't answer this question without knowing the client program so I'll skip it.

Or:

> How can I display a number from an Oracle query so that it is formatted with at least 2 decimal places?

Since `NUMBER`s never have any formatting of their own then this must involve a conversion to another data-type which can represent the number with a format (i.e. a string). So the result is that if you want a `NUMBER` data type then Oracle will not give it a format (but the client program might) but if you want to change the `NUMBER` to a string data type then you can give it a format (but it won't be a `NUMBER` as its now a string that just happens to contain digits) and, as described above, `TO_CHAR` does that.

Comment: Worth pointing out that changing the datatype to render a specific format changes the behaviour in other ways, as your example shows. That's why it's better to set the preference in the client is the better option.

Comment: I don't see where he changed the data type, or how it 'changes the behavior'.   He simply formatted the display of it in the query, which is exactly a client function.  If one wanted to hide this from the app, one could create a view that returns the formatted string. Well, I guess if the OP had a larger, unstated problem wherein the output of that query was being used by some other process, and not simply displayed to the end-user . . . but the fact that he cares about the formatting would indicate that this is just for display/reporting.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
select to_number(to_char(value, '9999999.99')) from dual;
```